# Error handling for find and remove the directory that returns error even after it is successful

Tags: shell, find

I am writing a shell script to find some old directories to replace them with the latest one. I used the following command. It is successful in deleting but I am running into this error.

```
-bash-4.1$ find /app/home/data01/dpx/ -type d -mtime +2 -name 'stress' -exec ls -ltr {} \;      
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 dpx app  1324 Oct 21  2017 relocate1.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 dpx app   316 Oct 21  2017 re1.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 dpx app 11876 Oct 21  2017 pre.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 dpx app  1241 Oct 21  2017 relocate2.sh
-bash-4.1$ 
-bash-4.1$ find /app/home/data01/dpx/ -type d -mtime +2 -name 'stress' -exec rm -rf {} \;       
find: `/app/home/data01/dpx/stress': No such file or directory
-bash-4.1$ find /app/home/data01/dpx/ -type d -mtime +2 -name 'stress' -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```

Why am I getting this error and how I can prevent this?

> find: `/app/home/data01/dpx/stress': No such file or directory

Comment: What happens if you add `-depth`?  What happens if you use `-exec rm -fr {} +` (using a `+` instead of a `;`)?

Comment: not sure how to use the +. can you please write a sample command for me?

Comment: Where you have `\;` in your `find` command line, use `+` instead.